# Issuing HTTP requests using IE proxy with AD authentication

Tags: windows, http, active-directory, ntlm, proxy-authentication

In a corporate desktop scenario, where the user is logged in to an Active Directory domain, I'd like my application to issue HTTP requests using the same proxy as Internet Explorer uses. The problem is that the proxy requires NTLM authentication using the credentials of the currently logged in user, which is something I don't know how my application could acquire.

Besides asking the user for his/her password (for which I found a lot of solutions), is there a way to do it the right, like using some native API? I'm not picky about programming languages in this case, if it works in this scenario, I accept it, although I'd prefer C/C++.

Comment: Which of the options did you choose?

Comment: I used WinINet, passed `INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG` to `InternetOpen`, and it worked. I also found that you can do something like that using [CredentialCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache.defaultcredentials%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in .NET, but I preferred a native way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are on Windows, and you are using domain logins, you should rather rely on Kerberos. Anyway, you now several options:

1. If you use WinHTTP , you simple have to enable it.
2. Use `libcurl` on Windows and it will compile with SSPI support by default.
3. If you use sockets by yourself, you have to call SSPI with the `Negotiate` package and exchange tokens per HTTP all by yourself.